# Getting Calabash values prints out only ****

Tags: ios, calabash, calabash-ios

I'm trying to get the value of a property using Calabash, specifically the "value" property on my "CustomSwitch" class. Here's the result anytime I try it:

```
irb(main):029:0> query "CustomSwitch", :value
[
    [0] "*****"
]
```

I get a similar output for just about every other view I try. Here's some more info about my setup:

```
xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

xcodebuild -version
Xcode 7.1
Build version 7B91b

calabash-ios version
0.16.4
```

If anyone knows why this syntax is acting funky for me I'd greatly appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> query "CustomSwitch", :value
"******"
```

This means that view matched by the query does not respond to the selector `value`.  If this is an on-off switch that is a subclass of UISwitch,
the correct selector is `isOn`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is displaying array of values

```
> query "CustomSwitch", :value
```

So, try this one

```
> query("CustomSwitch",:value)[0]
```

or

```
> query("CustomSwitch",:value).first
```